# Routee's messages was not delivered to the Sender

Tags: scala, akka

I'm working on a project which is running as a cluster and it was implemented by using akka-scala API. My application has mainly 4 actors. Those are Client, Dispatcher, WorkDistributor, and Worker.

My application.conf as follows,

```
cluster {
  seed-nodes = [
    "akka.tcp://application@<IP>:2553"
  ]
  roles = ["frontend", "dispatcher", "backend", "frontRouter", "dispRouter", "backRouter"]
auto-down = on
}

actor.deployment {

  lifecycle = on

  /client/router {
    router = round-robin-group
    nr-of-instances = 1
    routees.paths = [
      "/user/workDispatcher/router"
    ]
    cluster {
      allow-local-routees = on
      enabled = on
      use-role = "frontRouter"
    }
  }

  /workDispatcher/router {
    router = round-robin-group
    nr-of-instances = 1
    routees.paths = [
      "/user/workDistributor/router"
    ]
    cluster {
      allow-local-routees = on
      enabled = on
      use-role = "dispRouter"
    }
  }

  /workDistributor/router {
    router = round-robin-pool
    nr-of-instances = 1
    cluster {
      enabled = on
      allow-local-routees = on
      use-role = "backRouter"
    }
  }

}
```

Workers have been received works from Clients through the routers successfully,  but issue is messages which are send by Workers after completing the job is not delivered to the Client. My code for send message to the Client is "sender() ! JobComplete". This message was not delivered to the Client.

Additionally, Dispatcher and WorkDistributor are working as intermediate actors.

I will appreciate for any idea how I can resolve this issue.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: This is too dumb to be an answer, but I have a similar setup with a round-robin-pool and my worker thread replies with `sender ! command` - no parenthesis.  If that doesn't work can you please post the code where you get the actorRef for the router and dispatcher?

Comment: Message passing flow is successfully working with "round-robin-pool". But it is not working with "round-robin-group".

I had used "system.actorOf(Props(classOf[WorkDispatcher]), "workDispatcher")" to create Dispatcher and used "val router = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[Adder]).withRouter(FromConfig()), name = "router")" to create routers inside of the WorkDistributors.

Comment: I have a theory, but I need to know more about your worker actors. Can you post the code of your worker actors (their receive method and the procedures you call in response to the work request) ?